# error: Non-nullable instance field 'reverseMap' must be initialized. Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I'm using a service to create api from xml. I created model file from response. My model file is:

```js
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final economylistXml = economylistXmlFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

EconomylistXml economylistXmlFromJson(String str) => EconomylistXml.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String economylistXmlToJson(EconomylistXml data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EconomylistXml {
  EconomylistXml({
    required this.haberler,
  });

  Haberler haberler;

  factory EconomylistXml.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EconomylistXml(
    haberler: Haberler.fromJson(json["haberler"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haberler": haberler.toJson(),
  };
}

class Haberler {
  Haberler({
    required this.haber,
  });

  List<Haber> haber;

  factory Haberler.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Haberler(
    haber: List<Haber>.from(json["haber"].map((x) => Haber.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haber": List<dynamic>.from(haber.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Haber {
  Haber({
    required this.haberManset,
    required this.haberResim,
    required this.haberLink,
    required this.haberId,
    required this.haberVideo,
    required this.haberAciklama,
    required this.haberMetni,
    required this.haberKategorisi,
    required this.haberTarihi,
    required this.mansetResim,
    required this.izlesId,
    required this.yorumSay,
    required this.okunmaadedi,
    required this.anasayfamanset,
    required this.kategorimanset,
  });

  String haberManset;
  String haberResim;
  String haberLink;
  String haberId;
  String haberVideo;
  String haberAciklama;
  String haberMetni;
  HaberKategorisi? haberKategorisi;
  String haberTarihi;
  String mansetResim;
  String izlesId;
  String yorumSay;
  String okunmaadedi;
  String anasayfamanset;
  String kategorimanset;

  factory Haber.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Haber(
    haberManset: json["haber_manset"],
    haberResim: json["haber_resim"],
    haberLink: json["haber_link"],
    haberId: json["haber_id"],
    haberVideo: json["haber_video"],
    haberAciklama: json["haber_aciklama"],
    haberMetni: json["haber_metni"],
    haberKategorisi: haberKategorisiValues.map[json["haber_kategorisi"]],
    haberTarihi: json["haber_tarihi"],
    mansetResim: json["manset_resim"],
    izlesId: json["izles_id"],
    yorumSay: json["yorumSay"],
    okunmaadedi: json["okunmaadedi"],
    anasayfamanset: json["anasayfamanset"],
    kategorimanset: json["kategorimanset"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haber_manset": haberManset,
    "haber_resim": haberResim,
    "haber_link": haberLink,
    "haber_id": haberId,
    "haber_video": haberVideo,
    "haber_aciklama": haberAciklama,
    "haber_metni": haberMetni,
    "haber_kategorisi": haberKategorisiValues.reverse[haberKategorisi],
    "haber_tarihi": haberTarihi,
    "manset_resim": mansetResim,
    "izles_id": izlesId,
    "yorumSay": yorumSay,
    "okunmaadedi": okunmaadedi,
    "anasayfamanset": anasayfamanset,
    "kategorimanset": kategorimanset,
  };
}

enum HaberKategorisi { EKONOMI, DNYA }

final haberKategorisiValues = EnumValues({
  "Dünya": HaberKategorisi.DNYA,
  "Ekonomi": HaberKategorisi.EKONOMI
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues ( this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

There is this error : error: Non-nullable instance field 'reverseMap' must be initialized. on this line

```js
  EnumValues ( this.map);
```

How can i fix this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the `reversedMap` as non-nullable so you must assign it a value in the constructor. The solution is to make it nullable by adding a `?` like

```
Map<T, String>? reverseMap;
```

Comment: When i do this i get this : error: A value of type 'Map<T, String>?' can't be returned from the function 'reverse' because it has a return type of 'Map<T, String>'.

Comment: @Miktad then write `return reverseMap!;`